# Is it possible to downgrade my iphone 5 firmware from 10.2 to 7.1.2 by restoring to an old backup?

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, firmware, downgrade

Ok, so i made the most idiotic mistake of upgrading to the latest firmware on my Iphone 5.
I was running on 7.1.2. But now i'm on 10.2. Fack!

My friend currently has a working Iphone 5 with the firmware 7.1.2.

If MY FRIEND backs up his phone now that's currently on 7.1.2 on my laptop...
and if I restore my Iphone using MY FRIEND's 7.1.2 back up...
will i somehow magically be back on 7.1.2 and avoid the new BS update???

Answer (score 1):

No, this will not work.

If you're having an issue (or issues) with iOS 10 on your iPhone 5, perhaps post a question about these instead to try and resolve the problems. I know a few users with iPhone 5 models running iOS 10 without any issues whatsoever.